# How to map the clickable area on a SVG button / link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, font-awesome

I am using a Circle shaped icon (from the [font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) library) which acts as a button on my page. the problem is that the clickable area of the Icon is rectangular like any other HTML element.

is there any way to limit the clickable area to a circular shape so the button works only when you click inside the opaque area and not when you click on transparent bounding box?

I know that you can use maps to define clickable areas on images but Im new to SVG and could not find how to do the same thing with SVG.

I also tried `{border-radius: 50%}` but no avail. this is the Icon I am using and the HTML code:

https://fontawesome.com/icons/plus-circle?style=solid

```
<div id="new_item">
  <span class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-4x"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#newEvent_modal">
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `border-radius: 50%` for the `new_item` ? Does the `new_item` have `display:block` or `inline-block` and the same size as your icon?

Comment: @enxaneta No the `{border-radius: 50%}` belongs to the `<span>` element. the `new_item` is `display:block` and is just a fixed position container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of using `border-radius:50%` works for me:

```css
.floating-button {
  font-size:30px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin:2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

<div id="new_item">
  <a class="floating-button" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

#### Update

The OP commented that they are looking for a SVG compatible solution. Also in this case border-radius:50% comes in handy:

```css
* {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
svg {
  width: 1em;
}
a {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height:1em;
  margin:1em;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="new_item">
  <a class="floating-button" href="#">
  <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="32"><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8zm144 276c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12h-92v92c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12h-56c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-92h-92c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-56c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h92v-92c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h56c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v92h92c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v56z" ></path></svg>
  </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: This approach only works for WebFont icons but Im looking for a SVG compatible solution

Comment: Thank you for the the update :) I ran your code snippet and the button still is clickable outside the circle. if you move your cursor precisely to the bottom-right corner for example you'll see the cursor changes to finger pointer which is the same thing Im trying to avoid

Comment: I've added `a{overflow:hidden;}`  and a border to see the `a` element. I hope this solves your issue.